# global access to a collection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

where should i define a variable(collection) for it to be globally accessible both in all controller views and in layout? somewhere in Application controller or in session?

as an example

```
if current_user.has_role("admin")
 @groups=Group.all
else
 @groups=Group.all(:conditions => {:hidden => false})
end
```

@groups collection has to be accessible for rendering both in layout (in menu, for all other controllers) and in Group controller index view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it in action where you want it to be accessible:

```
def index
  if current_user.has_role("admin")
    @groups = Group.all
  else
    @groups = Group.all(:conditions => {:hidden => false})
  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

It will be accessible to every layout element for this action. If you want it to be accessible in all actions of one controller than add before_filter:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_groups

  def load_groups
    if current_user.has_role("admin")
      @groups = Group.all
    else
      @groups = Group.all(:conditions => {:hidden => false})
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

before_filter runs load_groups method before action method is run.

And if you want it to be accessible in all controllers then put the above example in ApplicationController.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the method into the application [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html) you'd be able to call it from your controllers or views.

in application_helper.rb

```
def membership
  if current_user.has_role("admin")
    @groups ||= Group.all
  else
    @groups ||= Group.all(:conditions => {:hidden => false})
  end
  @groups
end
```

This way you just call membership (or whatever you name it) from a view or controller.

Comment: IIRC ApplicationHelper methods are not callable from a controller, but you can include them so they are. Add this to your ApplicationController: "include ApplicationHelper"

Comment: Alternatively, have the method in ApplicationController and then call "helper_method :membership" in ApplicationController rather than including the helper.

Comment: Just wanted to write a blurb about why I picked a helper over a filter - if you're sure you need to load the groups on every request (or every request except 1 or 2), then the filter would be fine. By using a helper method you load the groups as needed and it's not something you have to think about as you add functionality to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Furthering [klew's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295586/global-access-to-a-collection-in-rails/1295643#1295643): putting this in a method called by a `before_filter` in your application controller:

```
  @groups = current_user.has_role("admin") ? Group.all : Group.visible
```

The `visible` method is defined by a `named_scope` on the `Group` model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :visible, :conditions => { :hidden => false }
end
```